# Copy table structure to new table in sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, copy

Is there an easy way to copy an existing table structure to a new one? 
(dont need the data, only the structure -> like id INTEGER, name varchar(20) ...)

Thx

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You could use a command like this:

```
CREATE TABLE copied AS SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 0
```

but due to SQLite's dynamic typing, most type information would be lost.

If you need just a table that behaves like the original, i.e., has the same number and names of columns, and can store the same values, this is enough.

If you really need the type information exactly like the original, you can read the original SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement from the `sqlite_master` table, like this:

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='mytable'
```

Comment: Tip - If you have added an index to your table (and you want it in your new table) you can retrieve its SQL from sqlite_master using: SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='index' AND tbl_name='mytable' and sql is not null; - Notice I'm using the field called tbl_name because the name field will store the name of the INDEX, not the TABLE

Comment: A detail but noted that `WHERE 0` seems not necessary to clone the table (with data and approximate typing).

Comment: Hi What will be the full statements as i am not good with it and i am using this for iOS app

Comment: @vp2698 The returned `sql` value is the full statement. And to ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 13):

SQLite cannot clone table with PK, defaults and indices.

Hacking by another tool is necessary.

In shell, replace the table name by sed.

```
sqlite3 dbfile '.schema oldtable' | sed '1s/oldtable/newtable/' | sqlite3 dbfile
```

And you can check new table.

```
sqlite3 dbfile '.schema newtable'
```

Primary key, defaults and indices will be reserved.

I hope this command can help you.

Comment: best and simple answer in my opion, although in my case it didn't work directly because of an index with the table name in a different case (lower instead of upper) and the index name already existing.
I just ended up doing sqlite3 dbfile '.schema oldtable' > cmd.txt, then manually changing the cmd.txt and then cat cmd.txt | sqlite3 dbfile

Answer (score 0):

sqlite> .schema

```
CREATE TABLE [About](
  [id],
  [name],
  [value]);
```

.schema command will give you structure of About-table how it could be made by programming SQLite interpreter by hand, typing in commands.

Paste in and execute, the CREATE block giving the table new name:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE [AboutToo](
  [id],
  [name],
  [value]);
```

.tables command now will show you have two tables, old and new, "copied".

```
sqlite> .tables
About     AboutToo
```

p.s.  sqlite> is command prompt you get in console after launching SQLite.exe interpreter. To get it go to www.sqlite.org

Comment: Seems CREATE TABLE Awe AS SELECT * FROM About;
does the same job, makes copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record - This worked for me:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    contact_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    last_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    phone TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

-- Two variations
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ( 1, "Donald", "Duck", "noone@nowhere.com", "1234");
INSERT INTO mytable ( contact_id,first_name,last_name,email,phone ) VALUES ( 2, "Daisy", "Duck", "daisy@nowhere.com", "45678");

.output copied.sql
-- Add new table name
.print CREATE TABLE copied ( 
-- Comment out first line from SQL
SELECT "-- " || sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
.output 
.read copied.sql
.schema
select * from copied;
```

Beware that this only works if schema is wrapped after `CREATE TABLE mytable (`.
Otherwise you'll need some string replacement using `.system`

Answer (score 0):

Yes by using the SQLiteStudio you can use the last icon in the structure table called create similar table from any existing table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, using .schema to get the original CREATE statement one can create a new table with identical schema, but that table will be empty.

If you want to copy all data as well, you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer :

```
> sqlite3 <db_file>

sqlite3 > .output <output_file>
sqlite3 > .dump <table_name>
```

The line above generates the dump of table that includes DDL and DML statement.

Make changes in this file, i.e. find and replace the table name with new table name

Also, replace `"CREATE TRIGGER "` with `"CREATE TRIGGER <NEWTABLE>_"` , this will replace existing triggers with trigger names with a new table name on it. That will make it unique and will not cause conflicts with existing triggers. Once all schema changes are implemented, read it back into database using `.read`

```
sqlite3 > .read output_file
```

This can be scripted in shell file using shell commands like :

```
echo ".dump <table>" | sqlite3 <db_file> > <table_file>
sed -i.bak "s/\b<table_name>\b/<new_table_name>/g" <table_file>
sed -i.bak "s/\bCREATE TRIGGER \b/CREATE TRIGGER <new_table_name_>/g" <table_file>
echo ".read <table_file>" | sqlite3 <db_file>
rm <table_name>.bak
```

For example :

If you have table T and new table is TClone in db file D with file F to be created : then

```
echo ".dump T" | sqlite3 D.sqlite > F
sed -i.bak "s/\bT\b/TClone/g" F
sed -i.bak "s/\bCREATE TRIGGER \b/CREATE TRIGGER TClone_>/g" F
echo ".read F" | sqlite3 D.sqlite 
rm T.bak
```

Finally, you can generalize this script by creating a parameterized version where you can pass source_table, destination_table , db_file as parameters that can be used to clone any table.

I tested this and it works.

Testing :

```
sqlite3 <database_file>
sqlite3 > select * from <new_table>;
```

should give you same results as original table. and

```
sqlite3 > .schema <new_table>
```

should have same schema as that of original table with a new name.