# Duplicating a SQLite table, indexes, and data

Tags: sql, indexing, sqlite

How do I copy a SQLite table along with its index(es)? I know this works for other flavors of SQL but not SQLite :(

`CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;`

Comment: Is this answer would be helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20798114/4265714